# Perl : Selective string substitution

Tags: string, perl, substitution

I have a text file which contains strings with prefix A_B_.

Example: `A_B_Monday`

I would like to replace all occurences of `A_B_*` with `X_Y_*` except when * is `C`.

So all strings that are `A_B_*` but not `A_B_C` must be replaced by `X_Y_*`.

How should this be done in perl?

Edit:1
The * above is a string. So all A_B_* that are not A_B_Geneva should be replaced with X_Y_NewYork.
perl -pi.bak -e 's/^A_B_(!Geneva)/X_Y_/g;' File.Txt does not seem to work. I am on Strawberry Perl.

Update:
This worked for me
perl -i.bak -pE "s/A_B_(?!Geneva)/USB_EP_/g" File.Txt

Comment: As pointed out twice already, that will fail for `A_B_Genevaxxx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe：

```
s/^A_B_(?!C)/X_Y_/;
```

or:

```
s/^A_B_(?!C)/X_Y_/i;
```

Comment: My command line program is as follows:perl -pi.bak -e "/s/^A_B_(?!Type)/X_Y_/g;"File.Txt    This doesnt work.

Comment: perl -i.bak -pE "s/^A_B_(?!C)/X_Y_/" File.txt

Comment: This came closest. I had to remove the ^ and apply the /g. Thanks a lot everyone. I am learning.

Answer (score 3):

```
s/^A_B_(?!Type\z)/X_Y_/;
```

Without the `\z`, `A_B_Typed` won't get changed to `X_Y_Typed` as it should.

You could use it as following:

```
perl -pi.bak -pe"s/^A_B_(?!Type\z)/X_Y_/g" file
```

Comment: Added one-liner to my answer.

Comment: The `^` anchor renders `/g` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
$line =~ s/^A_B_([^C])/X_Y_$1/;
```

You should do this for each line of your file.